# Google Analytics 4: custom dimensions in gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js, google-analytics-4

I am trying to send some custom dimension together with my event.
This is my code:

```
gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX', {
  'custom_map': { 'dimension1': 'age' }
});
gtag('event', 'age_dimension', {
  'event_category': category,
  'event_label': action,
  'value': data(),
  'nonInteraction': 1,
  'age': '666'
});
```

This is my dimension on UI:
[image]

I am sending my events together with my custom dimension, on UI I see all my data as parameters in the event,

[image]

but when I try to make something with my dimension GA just says me that there is no data for this dimension.

[image]

I don't know, probably I configured the map incorrectly or probably something wrong with the dimension which I created.
So the question, is my configuration and dimension correct? and if no, what is wrong? thanks!

Comment: You may have to wait a day for data to be pulled in. In the events report is it showing the age_dimension event, and if so does that event show a card for that dimension?

Comment: @TonyMcCreath yeah my event appeared today, but I don't see a card with my dimension. If on events page I add my dimension as a column in the table, the value for each row in this column is '(not set)'. If I click on any cell in my dimension column, I see page with such title - 'customParamDimension:8: (not set)'. Don't know what does it mean:(

Comment: Don't know. Check the date range you are looking at.